# In visual studio 2013 ctrl/f7 doesn't work

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013. I noticed sometimes <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd> does not compile the file. It doesn't give any errors and doesn't list the file. Here is a sample:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: DSM Driver, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I added a line with `...` which would create an error (C code). So I know it is not trying to compile. If I use <kbd>F7</kbd> it does compile and does spot the intentional error line.

A file in another project from the same solution does compile when I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd>.

So, I ran `Build->Clean` Solution but that did not help.

It is not a matter the file being already up to date because <kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>F7</kbd> will always compile even if the file has not changed.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "The file" - does this happen with every file, or only with a particular file?

Comment: What kind of project type is this? Web application? Winforms application? I ask because from experience, some web application project types does not actually compile anything.

Comment: It happens with every file in the project. The other project, which contains different files, has no problem.

The project is a C Console App, WIN32.

Comment: That compiles the file that's currently selected in the Solution Explorer window.  Not necessarily the file you are editing.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, General.  Tick the "Track active item in Solution Explorer" option to never get that wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experimenting. I recreated your problem quite by accident. I had made a folder with an apostrophe (e.g., Eddy's). I added my .C file there and ended up with a problem exactly like you mentioned. When I fixed my error (removed the apostrophe (e.g., Eddys) and the problem went away.

Comment: That was my problem. This explains why I thought it was an intermittent problem. Sometimes I use an apostrophe in a folder name. I wonder if this is a bug in Visual Studio. 

Thanks for your help.